# Killing a secondary Xorg stops display manager

Tags: debian, xorg, display-manager, lightdm, sddm

My computer runs on Debian Stretch. For testing GUI applications purpose, I'm using a second instance of Xorg on display :X (X != 0). After upgrading from jessie to stretch. Killing the secondary Xorg by its PID stops (crashes) the display manager leading me to a blank (black) screen and blinking cursor.

Note that with jessie everything was OK.

What can I do to diagnose the problem and solve it?